# Why my pagination does not work in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I implemented pagination for my Custom Post Type according to some documentation articles, but it does not work correctly.

After clicking on next page, my URL changes on /page/2/ , but posts are still same.

```
<div class="cpt-news">
    <div class="row">
        <?php
        ?>
        <?php

        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'news',
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'paged' => $paged,
        );

        $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ):
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="cpt-news-block mb-3">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-12 col-xl-6">
                                <a class="zoom-picture-hover" href="<?php the_permalink()?>">
                                    <div class="cpt-news-block-image picture">

                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-12 col-xl-6">
                                <h2 style="font-size: 20px;">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>">
                                        <?php the_title()?>
                                    </a>
                                </h2>
                                <p class="mb-3"><?php the_field('popis_inzeratu')?></p>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" class="cpt-news-block-link link-read-more"> <?php
                                    include get_stylesheet_directory() . '/assets/img/svg/icon_arrow.svg';
                                    ?>
                                   <?php echo "More";?>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile;?>
        <div class="">
            <?php
            echo paginate_links( array(
                'format'  => 'page/%#%',
                'current' => $paged,
                'total'   => $the_query->max_num_pages,
                'mid_size'        => 2,
                'prev_text'       => __('&laquo; Prev Page'),
                'next_text'       => __('Next Page &raquo;')
            ) );
            ?>
        </div>
       <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Did I implement something wrong? I seriously have no clue, which can be bad.

Comment: Please add URL examples.

Comment: my first page => http://tvorba-stranok.eu/ads/, second page when I clicked next http://tvorba-stranok.eu/ads/page/2

Comment: And what do you want the URL to look like? (I recommend you edit your post.)

Comment: It does not matter, what I really need is when i Clicked on page 2 for example, another 4 elements should be listed on page 2.. and etc... what do you mean by editing my post ? Really do not know, why it is not working

Comment: I have not tried this function yet, please where should I place it ? can you be more specific? maybe it will helps

Comment: To me, your post does not make clear what is your expected result and what is the deviation from this, sry. I had the impression it was about the URLs in the pagination.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187547/discussion-between-matus-vrsansky-and-jasie).

Answer (score 0):

Check the code where the custom post type is being registered. See what parameters are being passed to '**register_post_type**'. The rewrite parameter can have effects on pagination.

`register_post_type( 'news', $args );`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/

Comment: I created Custom Post Type in administration mode, not through code... should I try add it within this method ?